# Create a expander/panelbar control with asp.net mvc and css and jquery only

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, expander, radpanelbar

How can I create such a control: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/panelbar.aspx

in asp.net mvc with pure css and jquery ?

The first what I tried was to make it static by using a

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

but a ul-tag can not have a text so how could I give my subelements a header with text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) control that you could get inspiration from. The markup looks like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. The accordian is actually an expander/panelbar etc... The content div holds the subitems :-) This site has a nice css only sample http://theleggett.com/2011/05/04/csssitemap-system/ Just needs formatting and the click event for the header...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (it is originally for mobile apps, but I'm sure with some css changes, you can customize the look/feel)

[LINK](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html)